# Want to show masked input with current year after backslash in mvc view(razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Masking is working fine but I want to Auto generate year section by default like : 123-1234/(currentyear).

**View.cshtml**

```
<fieldset class="CreateEditfieldset Seconfieldset">
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DONO)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DONO)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DONO) // format : 123-1234/2014
</div>
</fieldset>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#DONO").mask("999-9999/9999");

</script>
```

It's editorfor Id is "DONO" and masking is working fine I repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible (hack-ish) way is to do this on the server:

```
$("#DONO").mask("999-9999/@DateTime.Today.Year");
```